# Grab specific value from middle of JSON String in Swift 4

Tags: json, swift, string, struct, swift4

I'm looking to extract only the link from this string and create a new string with that link, but I'm not sure of the best way to go about doing so. If anyone could enlighten me on how I can do this effectively I would greatly appreciate it!

String

```
{
    "timestamp": 1509507857555,
    "profileId": "e58d7f751c7f498085a79a37bf22f20b",
    "profileName": "Rhidlor",
    "textures": {
        "SKIN": {
            "url": "http://textures.minecraft.net/texture/1137b867b4a2fb593cf6d05d8210937cc78bc9e0558ad63d41cc8ec2f99e7d63"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your given string is JSON. You can get url from given JSON is like this :

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    var textures: [String: Textures]
}
struct Textures: Decodable {
    var url: String
}

let jsonStr = """
{"timestamp":1509507857555,"profileId":"e58d7f751c7f498085a79a37bf22f20b","profileName":"Rhidlor","textures":{"SKIN":{"url":"http://textures.minecraft.net/texture/1137b867b4a2fb593cf6d05d8210937cc78bc9e0558ad63d41cc8ec2f99e7d63"}}}
"""
let data = jsonStr.data(using: .utf8)!
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    let jsonData = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data)
    if let skin = jsonData.textures["SKIN"] {
        print(skin.url)
    }
}
catch {
    print("error:\(error)")
}
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for, thanks for the help!

Answer (score -2):

You can use these ways for fetch an url inside of any String.

Swift4

```
    let testString: String = "{\"timestamp\":1509507857555,\"profileId\":\"e58d7f751c7f498085a79a37bf22f20b\",\"profileName\":\"Rhidlor\",\"textures\":{\"SKIN\":{\"url\":\"http://textures.minecraft.net/texture/1137b867b4a2fb593cf6d05d8210937cc78bc9e0558ad63d41cc8ec2f99e7d63\"}}}"
    let pat = "http?://([-\\w\\.]+)+(:\\d+)?(/([\\w/_\\.]*(\\?\\S+)?)?)?"
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pat, options: [])
    let matches = regex.matches(in: testString, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: LGSemiModalNavViewController.characters.count))

    var matchedUrls = [String]()

    for match in matches {
        let url = (htmlSource as NSString).substring(with: match.range)
        matchedUrls.append(url)
    }

    print(matchedUrls)
```

Objective - C

```
  NSString *testString         = @"{\"timestamp\":1509507857555,\"profileId\":\"e58d7f751c7f498085a79a37bf22f20b\",\"profileName\":\"Rhidlor\",\"textures\":{\"SKIN\":{\"url\":\"http://textures.minecraft.net/texture/1137b867b4a2fb593cf6d05d8210937cc78bc9e0558ad63d41cc8ec2f99e7d63\"}}}";

  NSError             *error;
  NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"http?://([-\\w\\.]+)+(:\\d+)?(/([\\w/_\\.]*(\\?\\S+)?)?)?" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

  NSArray *arrayOfAllMatches = [regex matchesInString:testString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [testString length])];

  NSMutableArray *arrayOfURLs = [NSMutableArray new];

  for ( NSTextCheckingResult *match in arrayOfAllMatches ) {
      NSString *substringForMatch = [testString substringWithRange:match.range];
      NSLog(@"Extracted URL: %@", substringForMatch);

      [arrayOfURLs addObject:substringForMatch];
  }

  NSLog(@"%@",arrayOfURLs);
```

Comment: These ways are good solutions if there is a String not JSON object. but someone unliked it :) funny.

Comment: Yeah I agree, unfortunate that someone disliked it; I appreciate your answer! :)

Comment: With Swift 4 this should be done using the Codable protocol